# How can i install splashtop streamer on ubuntu server 18.04

Tags: splashtop

Hello im fearly new to linux, after getting smash a few times with this crypto locker and files in my home i desided to create a small server for my personal pics and videos, it all worked well aside from installing splashtop streamer. I have a bussiness account and cent seem to be able to install it.

Things i tried.
https://www.linuxhelp.com/how-to-install-splashtop-on-ubuntu/
https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/stream-ubuntu-to-windows-splashtop/
also installing from the store and nothing seems to work. im i missing something?

Comment: Can you show us some error of some sort?

Comment: thanks at least for taking the time, i know in windows i can get logs, nm i will find how to retrieve logs and send the error over to you.

Comment: Your logs are in `/var/log` check the `syslog` file

Comment: please give me a chance to read the logs, im used to windows and this ones are in plain text.

Comment: Do `tail -n 30 /var/log/syslog` will give you 50 line of entry in that file and welcome to the World of Linux!

Comment: thank you for the help, i cant load the file so i kind of had to send the scripts but i also realized i can send ypu a link to my google drive. my brain is kind of fried about now lol. hang on let me set this up with the link and delete all this nonsense .

Comment: https://compurexllc-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/manny_compurex_biz/Ei8go81dVWdPhtvfi4mUUSYBVHBwPL4LCr9Ry87mLL8YfA?e=RhLbJ0

Comment: Did you install in the root account as seen in that tutorial link you provided?

Comment: I see nothing in that file but I also see that this app is made for Ubuntu Tahr from here: https://www.splashtop.com/linux but that tutorial tries to make it happen on Xenial not even Bionic the version you running. I am afraid I won't able to assist you further, hopefully some one with expertise in this will come along.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you might be out of luck. According to: [Splashtop Streamer for Linux (Beta)](https://www.splashtop.com/linux):

> This version of the Splashtop Streamer supports Ubuntu 12.10 and
>   12.04; currently there is no support for other versions of Ubuntu or other Linux distributions